# Find records with MAX value in each

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using mysql. And here is one table, which I made for example:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ca23/1

In this table I've got fields:
`Country`, `City`, `Resource`, `Volume`, `other`

I need to **SELECT** records which contains **MAX** value of `Volume` field of each `Resource` each `City` each `Country`. 
I've tried these query:

```
    SELECT `Country`, `City`, `Resource`, MAX(`Volume`), `other`
    FROM `temp`
    GROUP BY `Country`, `City`, `Resource`
```

but data was messed up (at field 'other').

To be clear that's what I'm trying to achieve.

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ad62a/1

I need the WHOLE record, which contains **MAX**  `Volume` value.

I've already read [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) and know that there is a INNER JOIN - way to solve that
but don't get, how to do it with multiple grouping.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this updated Fiddle of yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ca23/4

```
SELECT temp.*
FROM temp
JOIN 
   (SELECT `Country`, `City`, `Resource`, MAX(`Volume`) AS MaxVol
   FROM `temp`
   GROUP BY `Country`, `City`, `Resource`) t
   ON temp.country = t.country 
   AND temp.city = t.city 
   AND temp.resource = t.resource 
   AND temp.volume = t.MaxVol
```

This query is basically making a INNER JOIN of your main table with the subquery which gets the max(volume) records for each country, city, and resource. The subquery results are aliased as table `t`.

Comment: Thabk you! I'll check it on my actual table and let you know the result

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not grouping on the `other` column, MySQL will give you a random value from within the group. In fact, other RDBMS such as SQL Server does not even allow you to SELECT a column on which you don't have an aggregate function or a group by.

So the solution, in your case, depends on what you want to return for the `other` column. Do you want just the value that belongs to the group that has the maximum volume? In that case, do something like this:

```
SELECT `Country`, `City`, `Resource`, `Volume`, `other`
FROM `temp` t1
WHERE `Volume` = (SELECT MAX(`Volume`) FROM `temp` t2 WHERE t1.`Country` = t2.`Country`
                     AND t1.`City` = t2.`City` AND t1.`Resource` = t2.`Resource`)
```

Comment: Note that this solution is likely to be slower than other, documented methods.

Comment: Thank you! It seems working too. I'll check it on my work table

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for help! Your variant is also working, but takes a bit longer, and that's important for me, because I've got a quite big table (about 55 000 000 records)

Answer (score 0):

And one more way in the collection using MySQL feature: [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

```
select Country, City, Resource, Volume,other 
from 
(
SELECT Country, City, Resource, Volume,other,
if(@c1<>Country OR @c2<>City OR @c3<>Resource,1,0) 
   as FlagField,
@c1:=Country,
@c2:=City,
@c3:=Resource
FROM temp, (Select @c1:='',@c2:='',@c3:='') as t1
ORDER BY Country, City, Resource,Volume DESC
) t2 
WHERE FlagField=1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ca23/25)</kbd>

This query also solves the issue when there are **more than one record** with `Value=MAX(Value)` per group. If you use a way with `JOIN` a subquery or `WHERE Volume=(..MAX(Value)..)` then you also should handle this issue with (for example) one more `Group BY` in the main query to leave only one record per group. For instance (@Aziz Shaikh query):

```
SELECT temp.Country,temp.City,temp.Value,MAX(other)
FROM temp
JOIN 
   (SELECT `Country`, `City`, `Resource`, MAX(`Volume`) AS MaxVol
   FROM `temp`
   GROUP BY `Country`, `City`, `Resource`) t
   ON temp.country = t.country 
   AND temp.city = t.city 
   AND temp.resource = t.resource 
   AND temp.volume = t.MaxVol
GROUP BY temp.Country,temp.City,temp.Value
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, but that seems too complicated for me. I need only one maxValue